# Extracting Window Contents

Tags: windows, screen-scraping, text-extraction

I need to extract window content if this is based on text, or at least the file path associated to that window.  To-date, I have considered:
1. win32api
2. 3rd party libraries
3. wrapper classes

However, I am not satisfied with the solutions.  So any ideas how this can be done in a clean way?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at autoit http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/index.shtml
it is a free scripting language designed for (among other things) screen scraping. even if you don't use the language, it includes a screen scraping utility that identifies classes and control id's of screen objects. that can be useful so in order to identify pieces of the window from which you can extract data (getwindowtext, etc) via another windows app.

-don